# Google maps show on localhost but not when deployed

Tags: google-maps-api-3, vuejs3

I am using [Vue 3 Google Maps](https://github.com/fawmi/vue-google-maps). The maps show on localhost but not when deployed. There are no key restrictions. Responses related to this on this platform have not helped. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

```
<GMapMap
    ref="mapRef"
    :center="{lat:-1.2142382752478131,lng:36.767487497132045}"
    :zoom="15"
    map-type-id="roadmap"
    style="width: 100%; height: 700px"
    @center_changed="centerChanged"
  >
    <GMapMarker
      v-if="schoolMarker.position.lat && schoolMarker.position.lng"
      :position="schoolMarker.position"
      @mouseover="schoolMarker.infoWindow = true"
      @mouseout="schoolMarker.infoWindow = false"
    >
      <GMapInfoWindow
        :opened="schoolMarker.infoWindow"
        :class="
          isSettingSchoolLocation ? 'text-danger font-weight-bold' : ''
        "
      >
        <div>{{ schoolMarker.title }}</div>
      </GMapInfoWindow>
    </GMapMarker>
    <GMapMarker
      :key="marker"
      v-for="marker of busMarkers"
      :icon="marker.icon"
      :position="marker.position"
    >
    </GMapMarker>

    <GMapMarker
      v-for="marker of markers"
      :key="marker"
      :position="marker.position"
      :clickable="true"
      :icon="marker.icon"
      @mouseover="onMouseEvent(marker.id, true)"
      @mouseout="onMouseEvent(marker.id, false)"
    >
      <GMapInfoWindow :opened="marker.infoWindow">
        <div>
          <StudentInfoWindow :student-details="marker.studentDetails" />
        </div>
      </GMapInfoWindow>
    </GMapMarker>
  </GMapMap>
```

Comment: Can you provide screenshot or piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

The style `style="width: 100%; height: 700px"` was not being detected. I have added the style for `.vue-map` class manually and it's now working.